# React Router v4 Google Analytics react-ga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

Hey everyone I have been trying to follow along with the docs to use react-ga in my React site. I am using the React Router v 4. I keep getting an error on my Google Analytics saying it can't find it, that there is not a valid tracking code, but I  do use my Tracking ID. Maybe there is a piece to the puzzle that I need that I am missing? Below is my index.js 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import Home from './containers/home.js'

import AllExplore from './containers/allexplore.js';

import Explore from './containers/explore.js';
let ReactGA = require('react-ga');

ReactGA.initialize('UA-MYIDNUMBER-1');

function logPageView() {
  ReactGA.set({ page: window.location.pathname + 
window.location.search });
 ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
        return(
 <BrowserRouter onUpdate={logPageView}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/allexplore" component={AllExplore} />

    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>


    );
  }
}
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my ReactGA Setup. I am not sure that it is ideal but it is working in multiple production applications. I also use ReactRouter4.

**GoogleAnalyticsTracking.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleAnalytics from 'react-ga';

import settings from './../../config/settings'

GoogleAnalytics.initialize(settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY /*, {debug : true}*/);

const GoogleAnalyticsTracking = (WrappedComponent) => {
    const trackPage = (page) => {
        GoogleAnalytics.set({ page });
        GoogleAnalytics.pageview(page);
    };

    const HOC = (props) => {
        const page = props.location.pathname;
        //Disable on dev
        if (!settings.dev){
            trackPage(page);
        }

        return (
            <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        );
    };

    return HOC;
};

export default GoogleAnalyticsTracking;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import GoogleAnalyticsTracking from './component/GoogleAnalyticsTracking'
import App from './App';
import reducers from './reducers';

const history = createHistory()
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), ReduxThunk))

const element = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Route component={GoogleAnalyticsTracking(App)} />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I tried to clean this down some to just code relevant to your question about GA. I just wanted to give you an accurate picture of what is working for me.